# Environment.NewLine in windows phone 7

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7

Im using a textbox set in xaml as

```
    <TextBox AcceptsReturn="True" x:Name="Message" Grid.Column="0"></TextBox>
```

If i type in a text with linefeeds and get the text it uses "\r" as linefeed. I was under the asumption by the naming of Environment.NewLine that it would then give me "\r" but instead it gives "\r\n"? Is it the Textbox in Windows Phone that is speciell or doesn't Environment.NewLine work in Windows Phone?

Edit:
To clarify my question. I was going to convert my text to html by replacing linefeed with "`<br/>`" and thought I could use

```
var myFormatedText = Message.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine,"<br/>")
```

but Environment.NewLine gives the wrong value.

Answer (score 0):

I append System.Environment.NewLine to Textbox's Text property using StringBuilder and i haven't had problems with that. have you tried that instead of using \n\r ?